# How to display the response of my API in Python using stored procedure with the key : value format

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I am making an API in Python connected to MySQL and in the query I call directly to a stored procedure, the problem I'm having is that I do not know how to do so that when I call the API this returns me with the key format: value, as it only returns me the results. could you help me in this please. This would be my code:

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import mysql.connector
import dbConfig

app = Flask(__name__)


# Ruta para el método GET que llama al Stored Procedure
@app.route('/api/ejemplo', methods=['GET'])
def get_ejemplo():
    try:
        # Conexión a la base de datos MySQL
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(**dbConfig.db_config)
        cursor = connection.cursor()

        # Llamada al Stored Procedure
        results =cursor.callproc('sps_reservas')

        # Obtención de los nombres de las columnas
        column_names = [desc[0] for desc in cursor.column_names]

        # Obtención de los resultados del Stored Procedure
        results = []
        for result in cursor.stored_results():
            results = result.fetchall()
            

        # Cierre del cursor y la conexión a la base de datos
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()

        # Conversión de los resultados a formato JSON y respuesta HTTP
        return jsonify({'data':results})

    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({'error': str(e)})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=5000)
```

---

This would be the answer

```json
{
    "data": [
        [
            1,
            1,
            1,
            "Thu, 06 Jul 2023 17:31:39 GMT",
            "Mon, 10 Jul 2023 00:00:00 GMT",
            "Fri, 14 Jul 2023 00:00:00 GMT"
        ],
        [
            2,
            1,
            2,
            "Fri, 07 Jul 2023 11:49:33 GMT",
            "Sat, 15 Jul 2023 00:00:00 GMT",
            "Mon, 17 Jul 2023 00:00:00 GMT"
        ]
    ]
}
```

---

but I want it to return the data for example as follows:

```json
{"id" : 1,
  "idCliente " : 1 
}
```

Comment: and what is the relationship between the returned data, and the expected data?

Comment: it is more for convenience when consuming the information from the front end, because for example if the data comes with key : value, I will be able to consume it for example data.name and so only show the name.

Comment: Why are the comments in Spanish? This is English-only site.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursordict.html) worked:

```
cursor = conn.cursor(dictionary=True)
```

Detailed example:

```
import mysql.connector # pip install mysql-connector-python

conn = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="user", passwd="pass", database="dbname")
cursor = conn.cursor(dictionary=True)
sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE 1"
cursor.execute(sql)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    row["col"]
```

If it not worked, use dictionary cursor:

```
cursor = conn.cursor (MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
```

Comment: thank you very much @Odilkhon, your answer really helped me, I just passed the parameter to the cursor and it worked. I show the code as it is in case someone else needs it.        `cursor = connection.cursor(dictionary=True)`